# DefaultWorkItem does not allow group in Assigned To

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've created a new process template with TFS Power Tools. I added a group [project]\Developers. I changed the type definition of the Task-type so that "Assigned To" has 2 rules now:

1. ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE
2. ALLOWEDVALUES ([project]\Developers in list)

Now when I create a default work item and open the Assign To combo, it shows me "$$PROJECTNAME$$\Developers. If I select this, upload the template and try to create a team project the assistent comes up with the following error:

> TF26214: Cannot save the work item. Fields with errors: Assigned To
>
> TF237086: The work item cannot be saved because at least one field contains a value that is not allowed.

If I remove the default work item the team project is created successfully and I can add a new work item by hand using the Developers-group in Assinged To.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised to see this question from you after this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174068/resolve-users-group-membership-in-assignedto-on-work-item-queries/10216714#10216714)

The answer is still the same: you can't use groups for the Assigned To field.

Comment: Thats wrong! I'm actually already able to assign groups in "Assign To". There are tons of examples of how to setup this. The questions is how to get the queries working with it.

Comment: You can remove the restriction in the Assigned To field to make it like a common string field, then allowing to store pretty much everything you want. BUT, that's all, you won't be able to query groups or other stuffs, TFS only deal with this field with content as VALIDUSER and nothing else.

There's no query feature to get what you want.

To sum up you removed some restriction in this field to store "invalid" values in regard of the whole Work Item behavior. Work Item Query, Reports won't act correctly.

Trust me on this.